IF formula using vlookup
I am trying to create an IF() formula using VLOOKUP(), my VLOOKUP() is this
=VLOOKUP(A14119,'CoO Flags Report'!D:L,9,0) 

but I want it to state no if the VLOOKUP() finds #N/A

Consider switching to XLOOKUP() as it also handles the #N/A  condition.

Use IFNA:
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A14119,'CoO Flags Report'!D:L,9,0),"No")

If the formula return #N/A error then the wrapper formula will return No instead.
